# single quote with single quote error in Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Are' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php, html

```
echo '<a href="url_to_delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to delete') ;">Delete</a>';
```

i am having problem on the single quote.
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Are' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'
 i tried change with

```
echo '<a href="url_to_delete" onclick="return confirm('.'Are you sure want to delete'.') ;">Delete</a>';
```

but the confimation pop out is not working.
i need to use on single quote but not on double quote for php.

Comment: You need to have quotes *for* PHPs strings. But also provide quotes valid *in* HTML *and* Javascript context. You can have PHP output some single quotes through escaping. Or use HTML entities.

Comment: i tried used the suggested method Reference - What does this error mean in PHP? but it doesn't function correctly. The pop out confimation box is not come out.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the single quotes with a backslash:

```
echo '<a href="url_to_delete" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure want to delete\') ;">Delete</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems is that you're not escaping your quotes in your string.

```
echo '<a href="url_to_delete" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure want to delete\') ;">Delete</a>';
```

The other one is you're echoing out plain html, you can exit php mode and simply output html

```
...
?>
<a href="url_to_delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to delete') ;">Delete</a>
<?php
...
```